How can a one get additional master proficiency (or something else) in order to get the critical specialization effect for a second weapon group?
My reason for this question is quite specific, but I would like to have it answered more generically since this might help others in the future if they search for this topic.
Generic
If a character wants to be able to have the critical specialization effect of a second weapon group, what can they do?
As far as I understood it, you need to have master proficiency for the selected weapon group.
A known example is getting level 13 as a fighter and getting master on all weapon groups.
Specific
We have a level 7 half-orc fighter in our party using the free archetype optional rule for champion for background reasons.
They are also our out-of-combat healer (all first aid feats available) for the same background reasons.
The player loves dual wielding characters with two swords.
It seemed to be sort of useless to have two sources of flat-footed (it cannot stack) so they went for a main-gauche as the off-hand weapon since it is good for dual wielding and has a bleeding critical specialization effect.
Currently they cannot use the critical specialization effect of the main-gauche since they are only trained in it.
So is there a way for accessing a second critical specialization effect which is useful?

Your question is, I think, more specific to the circumstances of the fighter than you think. Most other martial classes get access to Crit Specialization around the same level, from mechanisms other than Master proficiency, with a variety of different restrictions.

Also, though this doesn't change anything, your Fighter should be an Expert w/ the Main Gauche, not merely Trained.

Critical Specialization isn't tied to Master proficiency
There are many options, such as twisting tree Magus' Student of the Staff, that grant Critical Specialization directly. These are often limited to a specific weapon, such as the Butterfly Blade, or a specific weapon group, such as polearms. If a proficiency is required, it is typically Expert. Additionally, gaining Master proficiency does not necessarily provide Critical Specialization. For example, Champions never get critical specialization unless they select the Blade Ally (either at level 3 or the Second Ally Feat).
That said, Jason_c_o's answer correctly identifies 2 of the best ways to get what the player seems to want with your specific case, and I would only add that you could allow them to take the Legacy version of the Orc ancestry Feat, Hold Mark. For tattooing some type of torch or flame on themselves, they gain critical specialization with knives (and bombs). Obviously it's up to you and the player if this makes sense for their character.
Item options are pretty limited at this time. The only thing I see is a Talisman to gain the effect one time. Search used. A ready supply of these can easily be bought at your party's current level, or the Talisman Dabbler Dedication can provide 2+ per day with no money investment or need to manage supply.
Feats are a bit more extensive. Search used. Some of the results are Feats that provide extra Strike options with their own critical specialization, but I can't seem to word the search to remove those. Current options to gain Specialization effects are:

axe and pick, hammer and shield, or bomb and knife (Legacy Content Orc)
clubs (Magus)
brawling (Magus)
brawling and Monk weapons (Monk, Martial Artist archetype)
lion scythe's and sun sling (Bright Lion archetype)
bows (Archer Dedication, Expert proficiency)
two-handed weapons (Mauler Dedication, Expert proficiency)
hand crossbow (Drow Shootist Dedication, Expert proficiency)
butterfly blade (Butterfly Blade archetype)
polearms (Runelord archetype)
battle axe, hatchet, longsword, and shortsword (Viking archetype)

Divine Ally, from Jason's answer, is an option not listed because it's a Class Feature. A quick check leads me to believe that is the only Class Feature that both gives critical specialization and is available through its Archetype.
Additionally, the Weapon Familiarity* feats did not show up in that query, so Search that as well to find many more options.
*Critical specialization was added to the Familiarity feats; formerly, you would typically also have to take [Ancestry] Weapon Cunning to gain the benefit using Legacy rules if that Ancestry had it available. It's up to you as the GM if you want to apply the change to Ancestries that have not yet been remastered.

The Talisman is, I think a bit of a sleeper option here that ought not be ignored. Crits with the offhand weapon will be relatively uncommon, and the consumables are cheap enough to just always have one attached to the second weapon without much impact.

Additionally, for one (possibly Free Archetype, up to the GM) feat, they can get two for free each day if they take Talisman Dabbler. They could go back to taking Champion feats afterwards, they just would be restricted from other Dedications until they take a couple from Dabbler. This is arguably worse than the Divine Ally feat, but has its bonuses (can switch talismans if they find something better, leaves Divine Ally open to be Shield/Steed, etc.)

The best solution, for your specific character, is to take the Orc Weapon Familiarity feat, and replace the Main gauche with an Orc Knuckle Dagger. It has a higher base damage die, at the expense of the Parry, Finesse, and versatile S traits. More importantly though, it is an Orc weapon, and Orcs w/ the weapon familiarity feat gain crit specialization at level 5.
This does not provide scaling proficiency that will keep up with the Fighter's chosen weapon group. That is something that you won't get from any feat or archetype. (Historically, you could do this through ancestry weapon feats, and with some archetypes - Mauler and Archer especially. But the Ancestry feats are all being redesigned to close that loophole, and early reports say that PC2 has done the same for the archetypes.)
So the offhand weapon will always be at -2 to hit versus the mainhand. And that's in addition to the loss of to-hit from wanting to be the second attack, alongside, (presumably) a larger, non-agile main sword. Which, in turn, means that this weapon isn't going to crit very often anyway. All of this is to say that... if you want crit specialization... grab the Orc Knuckle Dagger and the ancestry feat. But, consider for a moment whether a unique crit specialization on the offhand weapon is actually sufficiently valuable to go out of your way for.

Your options are limited, but...
Your player's Orc can take Divine Ally at 6th level. If they choose Blade Ally they may designate the main-gauche and gain it's critical specialization effect. (Champion archtype, Legacy content)

...In your hands, the item gains the effect of a property rune and you also gain the weapon's critical specialization effect. (Nethys, Divine Ally, emphasis mine)

More generally, you're pretty limited to features and feats from other classes and archtypes. The Legacy rules mention weapon runes, but the wording has changed in the Remaster the say "certain effects," instead.

Certain feats, class features, weapon runes, and other effects can gran you additional benefits when you make an attack with certain weapons and get a critical success (Core Rulebook (Legacy) pg.283)


Certain effects can grant you benefits when you make a Strike with certain weapons and get a critical success. (Nethys | Player Core pg.283)

As far as I know no rune was available that granted access to the critical specialization, but you could always use a rune that adds the effect you want. For your player's orc that would have been Wounding, available at level 7.
